# Use DecimalFormat(#.#) with localization

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I can use `DecimalFormat` easily to format my numbers. Example

```
 DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
```

However, I need to pass this number to be formatted by Localization like this one

```
        DecimalFormat english = (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

How to combine the two ? thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You specify the [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) to use:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbolsEN_US = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat formatEN_US = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#", symbolsEN_US);
System.out.println(formatEN_US.format(-123456.789)); // prints -123,456.8

DecimalFormatSymbols symbolsDE_DE = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
DecimalFormat formatDE_DE = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#", symbolsDE_DE);
System.out.println(formatDE_DE.format(-123456.789)); // prints -123.456,8

DecimalFormatSymbols symbolsFR_FR = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
DecimalFormat formatFR_FR = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#", symbolsFR_FR);
System.out.println(formatFR_FR.format(-123456.789)); // prints -123 456,8

DecimalFormatSymbols symbolsIT_CH = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("it-CH"));
DecimalFormat formatIT_CH = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#", symbolsIT_CH);
System.out.println(formatIT_CH.format(-123456.789)); // prints -123'456.8

DecimalFormatSymbols symbolsHI_IN = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("hi-IN"));
DecimalFormat formatHI_IN = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#", symbolsHI_IN);
System.out.println(formatHI_IN.format(-123456.789)); // prints -१२३,४५६.८

DecimalFormatSymbols symbolsTHAI = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("th-TH-u-nu-thai-x-lvariant-TH"));
DecimalFormat formatTHAI = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#", symbolsTHAI);
System.out.println(formatTHAI.format(-123456.789)); // prints -๑๒๓,๔๕๖.๘
```

Comment: nice solution  :)

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer here :
https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Java/tutorials/Formatting.html

just `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);` before DecimalFormat object

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
```

Comment: That won't work if you need multiple Locales in a multi-threaded application.